# javascript run a method synchronously before invoking the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to show a spinner element whilst a bootstrap table silently refreshes every 10 seconds, but the issue I am having is that it won't run synchronously and instantly closes the spinner as soon as it has been shown.

Any help much appreciated as always.

Calling code...

```
setInterval(function () {

    $('#refreshing-running').show();
    refreshRunningTable(function() {
        $('#refreshing-running').hide(500);
    });
}, 10000);
```

Refresh method...

```
function refreshRunningTable(callback) {
    $('#running-table').bootstrapTable('refresh', { silent: true }); // this line needs to be synchronous and not callback until complete..
    callback();
}
```

Initial table setup if it helps...

```
function loadTable() {
    $('#running-table')
        .bootstrapTable({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/.../...',
            striped: false,
            pagination: true,
            detailView: true,
            detailFormatter: rowDetailFormatter,
            pageSize: 5,
            pageList: [4, 8, 16],
            search: false,
            showRefresh: false,
            onResetView: function () { bindDeleteButtons() },
            columns: [
                { width: '', field: 'a', title: 'a', sortable: true, formatter: aFormatter },
                { width: '', field: 'b', title: 'b', sortable: true },
                { width: '', field: 'c', title: 'c', sortable: true },
                { width: '', field: 'd', title: 'd', sortable: true }
            ]
        });
}
```